# r sum by groups for matrices

Tags: r, matrix, group-by, aggregate

I have three columns in my matrix

```
       [,1]       [,2] [,3]
          1 0.11651699    1
          1 0.03850202    1
          0 0.11651699   NA
          0 0.11651699   NA
          1 0.04110752   39
          1 0.03599296   39
          1 0.05440237   41
          1 0.11651699   42
          1 0.06298718   42
          0 0.11651699   NA
          0 0.11651699   NA
          0 0.11651699   NA
```

I am trying to create a fourth column in my matrix that stores the sum of column 2 for each group(column 3). The expected out below

```
      [,1]       [,2]  [,3]   [,4]
          1 0.11651699    1    0.155019 = (0.11651699  + 0.03850202)
          1 0.03850202    1    0.155019 = (0.11651699  + 0.03850202)
          0 0.11651699   NA    1
          0 0.11651699   NA    1
          1 0.04110752   39    0.07710048 = (0.04110752 + 0.03599296) 
          1 0.03599296   39    0.07710048 = (0.04110752 + 0.03599296)
          1 0.05440237   41    0.09290439 = (0.03850202 + 0.05440237)
          1 0.11651699   42    0.1795042  = (0.11651699 + 0.06298718)
          1 0.06298718   42    0.1795042  = (0.11651699 + 0.06298718)
          0 0.11651699   NA    1
          0 0.11651699   NA    1
          1 0.03850202   41    0.09290439 = (0.03850202 + 0.05440237)
```

Obviously I cannot use `dplyr` and `groupby` because that only works with dataframes and I am dealing with a matrix object. So i tried `aggregate(df1[,2] ~ df1[,3], df, sum)` and it worked but its not easy taking the results from the aggregate function and creating the fourth column as shown in the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this operation on matrix, you can use `ave` :

```
mat1 <- cbind(mat, ave(mat[, 2], mat[, 3], FUN = sum))
#Changing 4th column to 1 for NA values in column 3.
mat1[is.na(mat[, 3]), 4] <- 1
mat1

#      [,1]       [,2] [,3]       [,4]
# [1,]    1 0.11651699    1 0.15501901
# [2,]    1 0.03850202    1 0.15501901
# [3,]    0 0.11651699   NA 1.00000000
# [4,]    0 0.11651699   NA 1.00000000
# [5,]    1 0.04110752   39 0.07710048
# [6,]    1 0.03599296   39 0.07710048
# [7,]    1 0.05440237   41 0.09290439
# [8,]    1 0.11651699   42 0.17950417
# [9,]    1 0.06298718   42 0.17950417
#[10,]    0 0.11651699   NA 1.00000000
#[11,]    0 0.11651699   NA 1.00000000
#[12,]    0 0.03850202   41 0.09290439
```